# WindowsMediaPlayer (WMPLib, wmp.dll) is affected by weired changes

Tags: c#, windows-media-player, wmp

**EDIT: Go to the second update, for the easiest reproduce of this weird behavior.**

I'm trying to play and stop sounds with WindowsMediaPlayer library.

I've search for dozens of pages on the internet, all are saying the same code is required for basic playing.

But it just doing nothing for me.

```
        WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

        wplayer.URL = path; // relative path, absolute path, mp3 file, wav file.. I've tried everything
        wplayer.controls.play();
```

I just couldn't manage to make it play any sound.

Further more, if I check the currentMedia property, it recognize correctly my file,

but it claims its duration is 0:00.

Why is this happening?

**UPDATE:**

I've found that the answer to my problem is `Application.Run()`

I used a WinForms project, but deleted the Form, and the Application.Run line. (All my code was within the Main)

It turns out there must be a message loop for this to work (which is untrue for the `SoundPlayer` class by the way)

Also (probably for the same reason), in debug mode, when going from one line to the next, I just couldn't hear anything, until the GUI thread is freed.

I'm still so very curious to understand why is this?

Why does WMP require a message loop? And why does SoundPlayer not?

Or did I miss understand?

**UPDATE 2:**

*How to reproduce?*

New project -> Winforms -> Delete Form1 -> Go to program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        TryPlay(); // Do nothing.
        while (true) { }
    }

    static void TryPlay()
    {
        string path = @"001_The Beatles - Help.wav";
        WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        wplayer.MediaError += wplayer_MediaError;

        wplayer.URL = path;

        wplayer.controls.play();
    }

    static void wplayer_MediaError(object pMediaObject)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
    }
}
```

**BUT** if we change the Main:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        //TryPlay();
        new Thread(() => TryPlay()).Start(); // WORKS(!)
        while (true) { }
    }
```

Another option, is to keep the Main like this:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        TryPlay();
        while (true) { }
    }
```

but change the TryPlay method:

```
    static void TryPlay()
    {
        string path = @"001_The Beatles - Help.wav";
        WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        wplayer.MediaError += wplayer_MediaError;

        wplayer.URL = path;

        wplayer.controls.play();
        Application.Run(); // <------  WORKS. (why?)
    }
```

Comment: Is the regular Media Player app able to play the file?